# C# actions construct with mysql results

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a mysql database with data like username, date and share path.

the app can give r/w permit to a share path to specific user with an expiration date and all that data is inserted in mysql.

i want to be able to read row by row like a while, for each loop to read every row and if find a row with the exp date = today get the user and share path and remove the permits.

```
try
{
    string MyConString =
        "SERVER=localhost;" +
        "DATABASE=permdata;" +
        "UID=user;" +
        "PASSWORD=pass;";

    string sql = "SELECT expDate, user, sfolder FROM  permuser";

    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
    MySqlCommand cmdSel = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSel);
    MySqlDataReader dr = cmdSel.ExecuteReader();

    while  (dr.Read())
    {
        foreach ( *row that exp. date = today)
        {
            *get user and share path
            *myDirectorySecurity.RemoveAccessRule (user/share path)
        }
    }

    connection.Close();
    connection.Dispose();
}

catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    Close();
}
```

any idea would be great, thanks

i end up doing this, thanks Michael..1

```
try
        {
string MyConString =
    "SERVER=localhost;" +
    "DATABASE=permdata;" +
    "UID=user;" +
    "PASSWORD=pass;";

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet(); 
string sql = "SELECT key, fdate, user, perm, sfolder FROM  permuser WHERE fdate=CURDATE()";

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
MySqlCommand cmdSel = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSel).Fill(dataSet, "permuser");


foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables["permuser"].Rows)
    {
         string fuser = row["user"].ToString();
         string pathtxt = row["sfolder"].ToString();

        DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(pathtxt);
        DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
        string User = System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + fuser;


                myDirectorySecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(User, FileSystemRights.Write | FileSystemRights.Read, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
     PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));

                myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
    }

connection.Close();
connection.Dispose();
}


catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What do you find not working in Michael's answer or its OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-write your query to fetch the specific rows like this

```
"SELECT expDate, user, sfolder FROM  permuser WHERE expDate=GetDate()";
```

I have taken your code and re-adjusted it below.

```
try
{
    string MyConString =
        "SERVER=localhost;" +
        "DATABASE=permdata;" +
        "UID=user;" +
        "PASSWORD=pass;";

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet(); // Set a new DataSet instance
    string sql = "SELECT expDate, user, sfolder FROM  permuser WHERE expDate=GetDate()"

    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
    MySqlCommand cmdSel = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
    new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSel).Fill(dataSet, "permuser"); // passing the command into the DataAdapter


    foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables["permuser"].Rows)
        {
            //*get user and share path
            row["user"]; //User rows
             row["sfolder"]; //sfolder rows
            *myDirectorySecurity.RemoveAccessRule (user/share path)
        }

    connection.Close();
    connection.Dispose();
}

catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    Close();
}
```

Taking a proper look at the code above, you would discover that I have used a DataSet and eliminated the SqlReader because I find DataSet much easier and safe.

Comment: with that i get all rows with the today date. so i can apply the action the every row in the collection. then what can i use for the foreach loop ? a foreach user in [user] ?